# Crawl History Explanation sought

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, error, crawl, index

With reference to an example Crawl History, below, please could someone explain what the figures actually report:

[image]

In particular, the last 2 Incremental crawls show large drops in the number of errors reported but not similar increases in the Successes. Assuming that there aren't large numbers of deleted items, during this period, there thus seems to be a notable variation in the number of items found by the crawl! Thanks for any clarification you can give

Comment: Open Crawl Log (or Click on the number under Errors) and show us screenshots with the defining of errors and the url addressess of documents. There can be a complex solution to get Index to right state.

Answer (score 0):

It will all depend on what kind of errors you had. You need to review the crawl log to determine the error type and why that error didn't occur in the subsequent crawl.

It may be the case that the crawl rules have changed between the crawls thus eliminating some of the errors.